# Stability of difference equation $x_{n+1}=ax_ne^{-bx_n}$

Tags: recurrence-relations, fixed-points

> Determine the conditions on $a$ and for which the nonzero equilibrium value of $b$ $x_{n+1}=ax_ne^{-bx_n}$ is stable, where $a$ and $b$ are positive constant.

I have learnt the condition of stability of system of difference equations, but I have no idea on this problem and I can not express $x_n$ in terms of n, could you please give me some hints? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You've asked for some hints so I would start by considering different ranges for b (major clue: $b>0$ & $b<0$ due to the significance of the exponential sign in stability in infinite series)

Then consider what would happen if you kept calculating $x_n$ and what conditions you would have to apply for $a$ so that $|x_n|<\infty$

Comment: Let $f(x) = axe^{-bx}$, can I conclude that the solution is stable if $|f'(x^*)|<1$, where $x^*$ is the equilibrium value?